# How to split a sentence with spaces and punctuation into words, so I can use motion like in vim

Tags: javascript, vim

I am building a vim editor, and want to do motions like move to the beginning of the word, end of the word and start of the next word.

I thought I should split the line into words so I can get some context. So:

I have this string:

```
Assign "Caps-Lock" to "Ctrl", and "Tab" to "Escape" to use the commands easier.
```

I want to split this into something like this:

```
[`Assign`,` "`,`Caps`,`-`,`Lock`,`" `,`to`,` "`,`Ctrl`, .... ", and "Tab" to "Escape" to use the commands easier.
```

One rule is to not lose any characters in the split array. Second rule is to group the characters by words, spaces aside and punctuation aside. However vim does it.

I tried various regexes all failed for example this eats spaces:

```
function wordize(line: string) {
  return line.match(/[?!.]|\w+/g)
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Looks like `split(your_string, '\<\|\>')` can help you.

Comment: What language is that, it doesn't make any sense @RickHowe

Answer (score 1):

Here are some code that helps achieve what I want, just let me know if this has any bugs, or there is a neater solution.

```
function out_of_ctx(p: string, n: string) {
  let w = !!p.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/),
    wn = !!n.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/)

  return (w !== wn)
}

// TODO cache
function wordize(line: string) {
  let res = []

  let ctx = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < line.length - 1; i++) {
    ctx += line[i]
    if (out_of_ctx(line[i], line[i+1])) {
      res.push(ctx)
      ctx = ''
    }
  }
  ctx += line[line.length - 1]
  if (ctx !== '') {
    res.push(ctx)
  }
  return res
}

function words_n(words: Array<string>, n: number) {
  let res = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    res += words[i].length
    if (res - 1 >= n) {
      return i
    }
  }
}

function words_count(words: Array<string>, n: number) {
  let res = 0
  for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    res += words[i].length
  }
  return res
}

function beginning_of_word(line: string, n: number) {
  let wz = wordize(line)
  let i = words_n(wz, n)
  return words_count(wz, i-1)
}

function end_of_word(line: string, n: number) {
  let wz = wordize(line)
  let i = words_n(wz, n)
  return words_count(wz, i) - 1
}

function start_of_next_word(line: string, n: number) {
  let wz = wordize(line)
  let i = words_n(wz, n)
  return words_count(wz, i)
}
```